# Cron job to run python script won't work on Linode

Tags: python, ubuntu, cron

I have a Linode server using Ubuntu. I am trying to run a script `getprice.py`. I have run `crontab -e` and added the entry:

```
 */1   *    *    *    * python /var/www/mysite/getprice.py
```

However it is not running. Why am I doing wrong here?

EDIT:

I have changed the `getprice.py` to a simple `print "Hello world"` for testing. Checking the `syslog` I have:

```
CMD (/usr/bin/python /var/www/mysite/getprice.py)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

So I have added `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the cron job line. Now the output is:

`CMD (/usr/bin/python /var/www/mysite/getprice.py >/dev/null 2>&1)`

Comment: maybe it's related to the _contents_ of the script? Have you tried with a simple "hello world" script? if it doesn't work, post the minimal code ([mcve])

Comment: The dot at the end is suspicious. Please also add the syslog entry and redirect stdout and stderr to a file to get the Traceback.

Comment: @KlausD. dot was a typo. how do I add a syslog entry?

Comment: Check your logs, they are usually in `/var/log`. ("adding" = find the log lines from the cronjob and add them your post)

Comment: Why do you write `*/1` instead of just `*`? You only need `/` if you want some other multiplier than 1.

Comment: @KlausD. please see edit

Comment: when standard output is disabled, you cannot see if your program is doing something. Why not create a file and write "Hello" in it? (you must be sure that the permissions are right). If the file is created, then at least a "simple script" works;